# How can I modify this regex to exclude the name of specific folder match

Tags: regex, perl

I have this regex `$folder =~ / (?!\d{3}) /xmi` which I use to match inversely match folders that do not follow our 3 number naming convention. It also catches loose files I found out.

My issue is I need it to NOT match the name of specific folder called `Junk` which is something like recycle bin for my script. If the script wipes it then there is no point to having it.

How can I make that work?

Also, is that the correct way to do an inverse match in perl? I found that answer on some website and it works but could it be better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$folder =~ / (?!\d{3}) /xmi` almost certainly isn't matching what you intend it to match: it will match any point in a string that isn't followed by 3 digits.

This means it will match `"no numbers"` or it'll also match `"123"`, because it'll match against any of the points that aren't followed by 3 digits: the first digit is followed by only two, etc.

You're better off checking that `$folder` *doesn't* match a regexp that matches 3 digits, either by use of `!~` (the opposite of `=~`) or using `not` or `unless`:

```
if( $folder !~ /\d{3}/ )
{
    # Do stuff.
}
```

That will only check that there aren't 3 digits *anywhere* in the filename though, if you mean at the start or end of the filename, or for the entire of the filename, you need to anchor your regexp:

```
/^\d{3}/  # starts with 3 digits
/\d{3}$/  # ends with 3 digits
/^\d{3}$/ # consists entirely of 3 digits
```

Checking that the filename doesn't match "Junk" is best handled as a separate clause in your if statement rather than trying to make it part of the same regexp:

```
if( $folder !~ /\d{3}/ and $folder ne 'Junk' )
{
    # Do stuff.
}
```

You can't tell if something is a directory with a regexp, for that you need the `-d` operator, so to ignore files you need to check `-d $folder`.

```
if( -d $folder and $folder !~ /\d{3}/ and $folder ne 'Junk' )
{
    # Do stuff.
}
```

Finally the special directories `.` and `..` for current and parent directory won't match your 3 digit naming convention either, so you'll want to exclude those too if you aren't already.

Comment: Well the only folder I care about are named with exactly 3 digits. Anything else does not belong there. Except for the Junk folder.

Comment: Also my folder list is an array I dump everything into. I splice the `.` and `..` from the top of the list. I learned that one that hard way.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a regex and a comparison?

```
$folder =~ / (?!\d{3}) /xmi && $folder ne 'Junk'
```

As far as an inverse match goes, that works as well as anything.  The Perl philosophy is "There is more than one way to do it."  You could also do a check to insure that three digits are present, and then invert the result:

```
print "Bad folder name: $folder"
  unless $folder =~ /\d{3}/ or $folder eq 'Junk';
```